# Excel unhide sheet by codename

Tags: vba, excel

I use a Userform with command buttons that Unhides veryhidden sheets and then selects them by the sheet's codename so i can make edits to the sheet and then i hide them with another command button when i am done making the changes to the sheet.

But when i have (2) of the workbooks with different filenames open at once i get an the error.

```
Sub Show_Sheet()

BlankOptionSheet.Visible = -xlSheetVisible
BlankOptionSheet.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Avoid to use `select´. Try to define the sheet instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: Is the worksheet accessed by its code name `BlankOptionSheet`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug Yes. BlankOptionSheetis the sheet's codename

Comment: Can you clarify "more than 1 of the same workbooks open at once"? because Excel doesn't let you open two instances of the same workbook, you get a "workbook is already open" message.

Comment: @Niclas - selecting the sheet is the *point* of the code: no reason to avoid it here...

Comment: Is the form modal?

Comment: i use `.Show(vbModeless)` i guess that makes it Modeless?.
dose StackExchange have a website that you can upload file to be reviewed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Userform is in the workbook that is not currently Active at the time, the code will fail because you can't Select a Worksheet that is not in the ActiveWorkbook.  You should Activate the Sheet instead of Selecting it:

```
Sub Show_Sheet()

    BlankOptionSheet.Visible = -xlSheetVisible
    BlankOptionSheet.Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: that keeps the error from happening but when i run the code from the userform it's only changing one of the workbooks even if i close it and reopen it from the other workbook. i use   `Call BidSheet_User_Form.Show(vbModeless)` to open it

Comment: @luke it's always only ever going to work with one workbook. You need to get a handle on the other workbook for it to work on both.

Comment: @Mat'sMug changing `BlankOptionSheet.Select` to `BlankOptionSheet.Activate fixed the error, and it work fine now, i was using a shortcut key to open the userform and thats why it was still running the code from the other workbook.

Comment: I'm still unsure exactly what you're doing, but remember to mark the most helpful answer as accepted if everything works now. If you can share the working code I'd also suggest you put it up on [codereview.se] to get it peer reviewed and improved. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can reference the activeworkbook and the specific worksheet you want to hide by using:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("nameOfSheet").Visible = False
```

Then turn it back on by:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("nameOfSheet").Visible = True
```

Alternatively, you can use the code name of the sheet as well.

```
ActiveWorkbook.BlankOptionSheet.Visible = True
ActiveWorkbook.BlankOptionSheet.Visible = False
```

Comment: I'd upvote this answer if it explained why the worksheet can't be accessed by its global instance / with its `CodeName` as the OP asks. I'm sure this code works, but my understanding is that accessing a worksheet by its `CodeName` is more robust, and implicitly works off the `ActiveWorkbook` anyway.

Comment: Yes that would definitely work. Let me revise. I used the sheet name because if you're running excel on OS X, it doesn't allow you to change the codename.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - `"implicitly works off the ActiveWorkbook"` - I think, because the `CodeName` is referring to an object **within** a Workbook object, it would implicitly work off ThisWorkbook.  To access an object in another workbook (e.g. the ActiveWorkbook) you would need to use `ActiveWorkbook.BlankOptionSheet`.

Comment: Correct. Although this works via late-binding. Upvoted!

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.BlankOptionSheet` doesn't give you a compile-time error "Method or Data member not found"  ?  Even `ThisWorkbook.BlankOptionSheet` will give you the same error...

Answer (score 2):

See this quote:

> The only times you cannot use a sheets CodeName is when you reference a Sheet that is in a different Workbook to the one that the code resides.

From [ozgrid.com](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm)

Comment: @Mat'sMug I understand now. My sheet name and code name were the same. That's why it worked. I will try to change my answer. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Assuming OP is trying to unhide and activate/select a sheet in *the other* workbook, this is a major part of the answer. Well done!